# How to turn of module reloading in JEST?

Tags: node.js, express, testing, jestjs, supertest

I am using Jest to testing express REST api written in express.js and typescript using ts-jest. My problem is Jest loads app module (express) in every test suite, it lasts only 3-4 seconds, but there is ~80 test suites each containing a multiple test cases.

My first thought was to remove `jest.resetModules()` from global afterAll() function, but it didn't helped. Is there another way how to change this behaviour or it is feature by design?

setup.ts

```
import { sequelize } from '../src/db/models'
import seeds from '../src/db/seeders/test'

// multiple mocks of services
jest.mock('../some/custom/module/mocks')


beforeAll(async () => {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true }) // basically drop db and create clean one
    await seeds() // seed database with data
})

afterAll(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
    // jest.resetModules() //! This line was removed
    await sequelize.close()
    global.gc()
})

jest.setTimeout(10000)
```

global.ts

```
import { createJwt } from '../src/utils/authorization'

export default async () => {
// create some acces tokens and add to process.env
    process.env.jwttoken = await createJwt({ uid: 1 }, { audience: 'users' })
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest'
},
roots: [
    '<rootDir>/tests/'
],
moduleFileExtensions: [
    'ts',
    'js'
],
setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/tests/setup.ts'
],
globalSetup: '<rootDir>/tests/global.ts',
testEnvironment: 'node'
}
```

example test

```
import supertest from 'supertest'
import app from '../../../../../src/app'

describe(`[GET] ${endpoint(':id')})`, () => {
const request = supertest(app).  // every time jest hits this line in test, it load app again

it('no authorization token | code 401', async () => {
    const response = await request.get('/something')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    expect(response.status).toBe(401)
})
```

start script

```
POSTGRESQL_URL=postgresql://postgres:root@127.0.0.1:5432/database JWT_SECRET=secret node --expose-gc \"./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js\" --runInBand --passWithNoTests --logHeapUsage
```

Comment: We have the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @AlexNault I switched Jest for Mocha :) maybe there are some solutions for Jest now...